# Error retrieving information from user cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run the project, I get this line highlighted with an error:

```
string cartID = context.Request.Cookies["Cinemax_CartID"].Value;
```

The message is as follows:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: that means, the cookie is not there. did u set it or was it set in the first place? you should approach cookies very defensively.

Comment: No, I didn't set it. I'm just learning cookies. I took this from a book but they don't seem to specifically set it either. I'm confused.

Comment: dont be confused. first set the cookie, then get it. also u ll see how to be defensive against, cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to check if the cookie exists, if it does, then you can read its value in a safe way, otherwise you should initialize the cookie value or you would get a null reference exception.

This is actually the same pattern you should apply when reading items from the `ViewState`, `Session`, `Application`, `Cookies`, etc. basically you cannot rely on an external value, you should check if it actually exists

Try something like this:

```
if(context.Request.Cookies["Cinemax_CartID"] == null)
{
   // initialize the cookie
   context.Request.Cookies["Cinemax_CartID"].Value = initial_value;
}
myCookieValue = context.Request.Cookies["Cinemax_CartID"].Value;
```